# Triple integral cylindrical coordinates boundary

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

I'm confused on the boundary of $r$ in this following volume question:
The volume between $z+2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $z=0,z=1$.

I got the integral as
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{z+2} r dr d\theta dz = \frac{19 \pi}{3}.$$
which is the correct answer. However, I don't understand the limits for $r$. Visually, I see that the minimum it can ever be (in this region) is actually $2$, which occurs on the $x-y$ plane. Why is it actually $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum value a radius can be $|r|$ is zero, and the maximum is governed by the $z+2$ term.  From what you have posted, you wish to determine the volume of a solid shape, not a solid shape with a hole through the middle.  If the minimum radius $|r|=2$, then you would have a hole with radius 2+2 through your object.

- 1: integrate w.r.t component $\theta$
- 2: integrate w.r.t component r, which inserts the boundary condition of the radius w.r.t component z
- 3: integrate w.r.t component z

w.r.t = with respect to

### Edit: Reply to comment #1

> Hmm, don't think I understand. If x^2+y^2=r^2, isn't the minimum of r equal to 2 ? This is the radius of the smallest circle cross-section for z≥0. And then the radius r only increases from there. (Basically, since the definition of r is the radius a circle for a fixed z, why isn't it at a minimum of 2 since the smallest circle has this radius on the x−y plane (z=0))?

Yes, the minimum radius, conditioned on the $f(z)=z+2$ boundary will give $r=2$.  But, you are integrating the radius with respect to a condition not a value or an evaluated expression.

$\int^{f(z)}_0 ...dr$ gives a solid object bounded by $0$ and $f(z)$.
When you substitute f(z) into the radius, you then automatically condition the inner radius on the x-y plane because the function $f(z)$ governs it.  The evaluation of $\int^{1}_{0}dz$ sets the minimum radius as $r=2$ and the maximum at $r=3$.
Essentially, it is not the evaluation of the radius integral that holds the minimum and maximum radii, it is the evaluation of the integral of z after the radius integration, which sets the radius values.

### Edit 2: Further clarification and explicit formulation for question poster and other viewers

> Find the volume between $z+2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $z=0,z=1$.

1. You are using radius and height-use cylindrical co-ordinates it makes the problem easier to deal with.
2. The revolution is 0 to $2\pi$, integrate w.r.t $\theta$ accordingly
3. The z component is bounded by $z_{Lower}$ and $z_{higher}$
4. The radius component is bounded by $r_{lower}$ and $r_{higher}(z)$

Initial formulation:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{z_{lower}}^{z_{higher}}\int_{r_{lower}}^{r_{higher}(z)} r dr  dz d\theta$$

Integrate and evaluate w.r.t $\theta$
$$2\pi\int_{z_{lower}}^{z_{higher}}\int_{r_{lower}}^{r_{higher}(z)} r dr  dz$$

Now, the radius component is dependent upon component z, so integrate w.r.t r:
$$2\pi\int_{z_{lower}}^{z_{higher}}\frac{r^2}{2}   dz \Big|^{r_{higher}(z)}_{r_{lower}}$$

The lowest r can be is the value 0, and the highest it can be (unless bounded) is $\infty$.  It is infact bounded by the z+2 condition. Therefore giving
$$2\pi\int_{z_{lower}}^{z_{higher}}\frac{r^2}{2}   dz \Big|^{z+2}_{0}=
\pi\int_{z_{lower}}^{z_{higher}} ((z+2)^2-0^2) dz$$

$$ \pi\int_{z_{lower}}^{z_{higher}} z^2+4z^2+4 dz$$
$z_{lower}=0$ and $z_{higher}=1$

Evaluating to $\frac{19}{3}\pi$

Comment: Hmm, don't think I understand. If $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, isn't the minimum of $r$ equal to $2$? This is the radius of the smallest circle cross-section for $z \geq 0$. And then the radius $r$ only increases from there. (Basically, since the definition of $r$ is the radius a circle for a fixed $z$, why isn't it at a minimum of $2$ since the smallest circle has this radius on the $x-y$ plane ($z=0$))?

Comment: edited answer to update with reply to your comment.

Comment: Appreciated, Still confused. I'm going to keep reading your comment to make sense of it, but even though I know that it's the condition, I still would've thought it was 2.   
I'll give an example in double integrals that shows a similar condition and might tell you exactly what I'm confused with in the next comment.

Comment: The area ecnlsoed by $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ in polar coordinates.
Substituting $x=r\cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$, we get the condition that $r \leq 2\sin \theta$. Now, geomtrically, I can see that $r$ is at minimum 0. Which is when $\theta = 0$. So it will be the integral $I = \int_{0}^{pi} \int_{0}^{2 \sin \theta} r dr d \theta$. $r$ here at minimum, is $0$.  
Also, when we have those $z$ bounds from $0$ to $1$, it kind of suggests to me that the min. radius and max. radius is in fact $2$ and $3$ respectively, maybe this could be a reason why the lower bound for $r$ is 1 as you said.

Comment: I have edited further for step by step, intuitive, formulation.  I didn't see your comment until after i had done so.

Comment: lower bound for r at point of integration is 0, z+2 increase this to 2

Comment: Much appreciated, I understand now.